# Monaca Certificate Issues

Tags: certificate, phonegap, keychain

I am trying this program called Monaca to replace phonegap, and I am getting some errors I need help on. I am getting two errors: 1.) Certificate not Registered, and 2.) Provisioning Profile not registered. How do I fix these?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because iOS Build Setings is not set up.
Please check the following documentation

Configure iOS Build Settings

https://docs.monaca.io/en/products_guide/monaca_ide/build/ios/build_ios/#configure-ios-build-settings